# How to pass iOS Build number from fastlane script to .circleci/config.yml

Tags: ios, testflight, circleci, fastlane

I need to "return" value from fastlane script to config.yml **(this question is not about how to pass parameters from config.yml to fastlane script,  the question is about returning back the data from fastlane to config.yml)** and save it in $ENV dictionary (propably).

This is a part of config.yml where I want to send a slack notification if the build is successfully sent to Testflight

```
# .circleci/config.yml
build_steps:
steps:
  - restore_cache: *restore_git_cache
  - checkout
  - save_cache: *save_git_cache
  - restore_cache: *restore_gem_cache
  - run: *bundle_install
  - save_cache: *save_gem_cache
  - run: *pod_install
  - run: bundle install
  - run:
      name: Fastlane
      command: bundle exec fastlane $FASTLANE_LANE
  - store_artifacts:
      path: output
      destination: output
  - slack/notify:
      event: pass
      channel: $SLACK_DEFAULT_CHANNEL
      custom: '<slack_template >$BUILD_NUMBER_FROM_FASTLANE_SCRIPT_THAT_I_NEED'</slack_template>
```

This is a part of fastlane/Fastfile file

```
# fastlane/Fastfile
desc "My App Upload to Testflight"
lane :upload_testflight do | options |

api_key = app_store_connect_api_key()

build_number = latest_testflight_build_number(
  api_key: api_key,
  app_identifier: "my.app.dev.com"
)

increment_build_number({
  build_number: build_number + 1 // THIS VALUE I NEED IN MY .circleci/config.yml for slack notification
})
```